# Sending data from a java server in a consecutive way

Tags: java, gml

Here is my java server code:

```
public class CaspSocket {

    private Socket socket = null;
    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private BufferedReader in = null;

    public CaspSocket(InetAddress caspAddress, int caspPort) throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(caspAddress, caspPort);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }
```

I use "out" to send data

```
out.print(1 + "|");
out.print(2 + "|");                                 
out.print(3 + "|");
```

It will be received in GameMaker Studio as follows:

```
var in_buff = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "buffer");
test_string=buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);
```

This way everything will be put into a single string

> test_string="1|2|3|"

However I want to receive the data in in a consecutive way

```
var in_buff = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "buffer");
test_string=buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);
test_string2=buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);        
test_string3=buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);
```

to give

> test_string="1|" test_string2="2|" test_string3="3|"

How do I send data from the java server in a consecutive way so that each chunk of data can be read out individually using `buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);` in GameMaker Studio

Edit: 
I have read the using buffers section the problem is when I send in GameMaker Studio to the server using this:

```
buffer_seek(Buffer, buffer_seek_start, 0);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_string, string(1) + chr(10)); //chr(10) means new line    
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_string, string(2) + chr(10));
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_string, string(3) + chr(10));
network_send_raw(Socket, Buffer, buffer_tell(Buffer));
```

The java server will only send back one string:

```
var in_buff = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "buffer");    
buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);
```

I don't know how this should be send sequentially using the java server, like it can be received in GM:S:

```
var in_buff = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "buffer");
test_string=buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);
test_string2=buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);        
test_string3=buffer_read(in_buff, buffer_string);
```

I will only be using buffer_string to make things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket communication is based on the concept of streams. Streams are plain sequence of bytes and there is no way how you can control how they are sent. The actual transport is managed by the OS protocol driver and is not accessible from applicatio level. So based on the multiple conditions

```
out.print(1 + "|");
// some other code
out.print(2 + "|");                                 
// some other code
out.print(3 + "|");
```

may be delivered in a single packet or several packets. Even `flush()` method will just push data to OS buffer and guarantee you nothing about the actual delivery.

So to read messages sequentially you should ether

1. Know their sizes and read into buffers of expected size (you may send some kind of *"header"* of fixed size data first which will tell the size of the *"body"* data next, then next *"header"* and so on)
2. Read full available content and split it in your client app using data delimeters (it your case this seem to be `|` character)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried method 2 before as I am not very experienced with java. In GameMaker Studio storing the full content in a variable and splitting it, however while doing this other data may be received and stored in the same variable causing data to get mixed. Which java code should be used for method 1 in this case?

Comment: Please check on [Using Buffers](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/buffers/using%20buffers.html) to learn about how data may be sent and read.

Comment: Going with #2 you can have centralized reader that later distribute received messages in your app base on content.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how the java code should look like using method 1. As for method 2 I don't understand what you mean with distributing the messages,  can you explain in more detail please?  I use a switch statement to determine  the type of event to be processed, however when a client receives a data package containing : "1|2|3|4|" it is being split however when it receives another package : "5|2|3|8" the previous data gets overwritten while being split. because data received is stored in a single variable,

Comment: The best what I can suggest to you at this point is to take some time for self education. Check on this article (it is in JS but should give you quite a overview of the concept): https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-implement-and-use-a-message-queue-in-your-game--cms-25407